# Image upload in AngularJs

Tags: apex, angularjs

Is there any good practice for uploading an image through AngularJs in salesforce without using the third party plugins.

Comment: Can you add your code how you are converting ? Prev I did with javascript..

Comment: Sorry @Ratan. I didn't have proper formatted code. I have used 3rd party plugin

Comment: Rv1 I have a simple example with `<input type="file">` we will grab the blob data of image and assign to Controller variable and convert that data to blob and create document in salesforce.. This example will work for you ?

Comment: Thanks Ratan. I have an idea of that. Here, i don't want to use apex class or javascript. Need to know the process of saving it through AngularJs.